# paypal access token not returning

Tags: java, paypal

I trying to send a payment with my test application. Im using the paypal java sdk package.

Im not receiving my access token. Im receiving only the bearer token, 
Bearer WesirDWp61YcTr8N8XWZHnPk7tCch.ZgcMvLfyp-FRA : appId :
 APP-80W284485P519543T

Thus when I try to send a payment Im getting and 401 authorization error because of no access token. The first time I sent the request it returned the access token but every subsequent attempt brings this error:

Java exception "com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 401
with response : Server returned HTTP resp" when calling method "create" with 
signature "(Ljava.lang.String;)Lcom.paypal.api.payments.Payment;" in class
"com.paypal.api.payments.Payment".

I do not understand what is happening here . Am I completely missing the boat here?

Thank You for any response.

Comment: Please write the code you used.

Comment: It is the java code that you can download from the paypal gethub. No changes have been made. I just trying to run the code on our system.

Comment: How do I place a response. Im only getting access to comment. And I cant put anything longer than about 100 characters

Answer (score 1):

Hit this URL with POST Request on Postman.
POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
On Authorization choose basic auth and enter the username as a clientID and password as a ClientSecret.
In Header set Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
In Body seelect x-www-form-urlencoded and write grant_type: client_credentials
after that send request you will get the access_token

Answer (score 0):

The bearer token is the access token, more specifically it is the type of access token returned.  As per the REST API Reference (which is what the java sdk calls), the call to the oauth end point returns:

{
  "scope": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*",
  "access_token": "EEwJ6tF9x5WCIZDYzyZGaz6Khbw7raYRIBV_WxVvgmsG",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "app_id": "APP-6XR95014SS315863X",
  "expires_in": 28800
}

The SDK combines the two fields and returns them as the "Bearer token".

This bearer token is all you need to access the REST APIs (with some restrictions based on the permissions/scopes requested and how the bearer token was requested, however that is dependent on creation call).  Pass the bearer token in the authorization header:
"Authorization: Bearer EEwJ6tF9x5WCIZDYzyZGaz6Khbw7raYRIBV_WxVvgmsG"

Comment: I dont understand this website. How do I post a reply?

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand what you mean by combining the two fields. I cant send the bearer token, it gets rejected. How do I post replies on this website. There is not enough space.

Comment: I give up on paypal. I cant get ANY support. This is the ONLY response Ive ever gotten from paypal. After NUMEROUS requests for help. And it doesnt make sense to me. Forget it

Comment: HTTP Authorization header in this case should contain the token type and the access token separated by a space => "Authorization: Bearer EEwJ6tF9x5WCIZDYzyZGaz6Khbw7raYRIBV_WxVvgmsG", authorization header takes several types of credentials, typically the first word identifies the type, and then the credential itself.

Comment: It's still being rejected. I dont care what you call it.

Comment: What data "exactly" do I send to paypal to get it to accept it. Im going by the instructions from paypal in the sdk example. It say's to send the "access token". Going through all that above, I dont have a clue of what Im supposed to do.

Comment: This website is very hard to operate